# Entity framework random fails database access

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, iis

I'm using Entity Framework to work with my database.
I created a WCF service, installed on IIS.

This service receives a lot of requests and, every time, it has to update some records in the database. Sometimes, it seems randomly, the data access fails, with this message:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Si è
>   verificato un errore di rete o specifico dell'istanza mentre si
>   cercava di stabilire una connessione con SQL Server. Il server non è
>   stato trovato o non è accessibile. Verificare che il nome dell'istanza
>   sia corretto e che SQL Server sia configurato in modo da consentire
>   connessioni remote. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 -
>   Errore nell'individuazione del server/dell'istanza specificata)

The stack trace is

> in
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager)
>
> in
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> in
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)
>
> in
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)
>
> in
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal&  connection)
>
> in
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
> in
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)
>
> in
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> in
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)
>
> in
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)
>
> in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>
> in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>
> --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
>
> in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean
>   shouldMonitorTransactions)
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>
> in
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>
> in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>
> in System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)
>
> in Myservice.UpdateState(String ID, String codiceStato, String
>   info, Boolean inviaEmail, String dal) in C:\MyService.svc.cs:riga 52

The code line 52, written in the stack trace, is:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var f = db.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);  //this line throws the error
    ...
```

Since the connection string is always the same (in the web.config file) and the most of the request are successfull, why sometimes this code throws the exception reported above?

Any suggestions is appreciated, I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: Most people here are English speakers, and can't understand that error message.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, i would start looking at network problems packet collisions, or other non code related issues

Comment: A network or instance-specific error occurred while trying to establish a connection with SQL Server. The server was not found or is not accessible. try to run ping -t to your db server seems like you have network problems

Comment: ping <ip> -t -l 200 and see if you have connection drops

Comment: If the WCF service is handling a large number of requests when this error typically then you could be facing a situation where the SQL Server instance is over-inundated with requests and doesn't respond in-time.  Depending on how your EF code is constructed with regards to how the data is loaded, lazy loading, etc. there can be a number of improvements you might be able to make to reduce the number of connections used per WCF request. Outside of that you could look at network-related causes, does the connection string use a DNS or IP address?

Comment: @StevePy Ip Address :) which improvements can I make?

Comment: It would depend on the types of requests being made when under load, not just the call that trips out because it cannot get any further connection. Performance/connection hogs include things like lazy-load hits or lack of optimizations to reduce the # or duration of SQL calls. (Loading larger amounts of data than are needed.) The code will appear to work just fine up to a point but then hits a brick wall where it cannot scale past due to concurrent connections to the DB.

Comment: @StevePy and...so? what can I try?

Comment: I'd probably start by pointing a development environment version of the service at an isolated database server and hook a profiler up to the database, then hit the services various endpoints while monitoring the queries going across to the database. This will provide clues to where lazy load calls or excessive reads might be occurring. For instance if one call stems off dozens of database hits then you can see the impact of a service designed to receive hundreds of simultaneous requests. Look at each query that is run and justify it's existence. Eliminate with prejudice.

Comment: Use an isolated database server to cut down on "noise" from other services/uses. Profilers generally track at a server level, not per database without extra filtering. SSMS I believe has a profiler, or consider Express Profiler for SQL Server..